# Arrays in javascript with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an array with would hold all option element values and html text. And in a result I would like something like this:

```
console.log( myArray );
```

output:

```
[ "htmlText" : '0', "htmlText2" : '1', ... ]
```

if this is possible, how can I access them and get their keys?

or at least 2dim array

How Can I do that?

this is what I have now:

```
function optionValues( selectEl )
{
    var values = [];
    if ( selectEl.length )
    {
        $(selectEl).find('option').each( function(){
            values.push( $(this).val()  );
        });
        return values;
    }
    else
    return false;
}


function optionHtmls( selectEl )
{
    var html = [];
    if ( selectEl.length )
    {
        $(selectEl).find('option').each( function(){
            html.push( $(this).html()  );
        });
        return html;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not an array. It sounds like what you really want is an object.

Comment: In php it would be an array. Dont know if it is here.

Comment: In PHP, arrays are associative. This is the same as objects in JavaScript.

Comment: And in Javascript, arrays are objects. Neat, huh? But a special kind of object, indeed.

Comment: @MaxArt Arrays are also objects in other OO languages...

Comment: @plalx I haven't said it was true for Javascript *only*. Anyway, it's not like an `ArrayList` in Java is a Java object just like a Javascript array is a Javascript object. What I meant is that plain objects in Javascript are hash maps, while arrays are *still* hash maps, but with numerical keys (and some more properties and methods inherited from the prototype). It's similar to PHP, but in PHP they call hash maps "arrays".

Answer (score 4):

The function can be simplified:

```
function optionValues(selectEl) {
    var options = {};
    $(selectEl).find('option').each(function() {
        options[this.label] = this.value;
    });
    return options;
}

console.log(optionValues('select')) // {Text 1: "1", Text 2: "2", Text 3: "3"}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c5e3vemo/

Answer (score 1):

Use `{}` instead of `[]` to make an associative array.

```
var values = {
  htmlText: 0,
  htmlText2: 1,
};

console.log(values['htmlText']);
```

To append things to an associative array (also referred to as an object):

```
values['stuff'] = 'foo';
values['thing'] = 'bar';
```

To loop over this:

```
for (var key in values) {
  /* check to make sure it's actually a valid key */
  if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " => " + values[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object would suit your needs best in this case. You can use `map()` to create one from the `option` elements in any given `select`. Try this:

```
var values = $('#mySelect option').map(function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj[$(this).text()] = $(this).val();
    return obj;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jco79gj9/)

Given this HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Foo</option>
    <option value="2">Bar</option>
</select>
```

The returned object would look like this:

```
[
    { "Foo": "1" },
    { "Bar": "2" }
]
```